# AjaxControlToolkit Accordion and databinding

Tags: c#, ajax, accordion

I'm using the HeaderTemplate and the ContentTemplate of the Accordion
control and binding it to a datatable. For some reason it doesn't
display any data. If I bind the datatable to a datalist it works as
ecpected, is this a known issue or am i doing something completely
wrong. I'm binding the accordion control in the code behind if this
makes any difference. Here is the code:

```
<cc1:Accordion ID="databoundaccordion" runat="server" AutoSize="None"  
HeaderCssClass="articleHeader" HeaderSelectedCssClass="articleHeaderSelected" 
ContentCssClass="articleBody" FadeTransitions="true" 
SuppressHeaderPostbacks="true" RequireOpenedPane="true" 
TransitionDuration="250" FramesPerSecond="40">
<HeaderTemplate>
    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "name")%>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ContentTemplate>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <a href="Articles.aspx">Go</a>
</ContentTemplate>
```

and in the c# code behind:

```
databoundaccordion.DataSource = presenter.getDataTable();
databoundaccordion.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have difficulties binding an Accordion to a DataTable object.
Instead, do the following by converting it into a DataTableReader and it should work just fine:

```
databoundaccordion.DataSource
                    = new System.Data.DataTableReader(presenter.getDataTable());
databoundaccordion.DataBind();
```

Here's another example with sample data:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("HeaderText");
dt.Columns.Add("ContentText");

dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Heading 1", "Content 1" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Heading 2", "Content 2" });

databoundaccordion.DataSource = new System.Data.DataTableReader(dt);
databoundaccordion.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just built a simple example which works fine.

rather than using `Databinder.Eval(Container.Item, "name")` I used `Eval("name")`

this seems to work with the simple example, I will update when I've tested with my working code.

Comment: ok so I tried to use my simple example in my working code and it still didn'y. I have since found that if i retrieve the data source from a database using a table adapter then databinding to an accordion works perfectly fine. However what I am trying to do is create a set of dummy table data programatically so I'm starting a new question about that.